# Binding ajax data to Bootgrid not showing result

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I am facing issue on search functionality.I am searching data and while key in any value & debug gave me error on below line:

```js
if (column.searchable && column.visible &&
                    column.converter.to(row[column.id]).search(searchPattern) > -1)
```

My implementation:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
sendRESTQuery(asmx());
});
function asmx() { 
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;  
    var asmx =  url + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/AD?$select=Column1,Column2,Column5,Column7,Column9";   //?$select=Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
   
    return asmx;
}
function testBtn() {
sendRESTQuery(asmx());
}
var baseUrl = asmx();

function sendRESTQuery(baseUrl) { 
   
    $.ajax({        
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',       
        url: baseUrl,
         headers: { 
            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(), 
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
        }, 
        post: function () {alert('true')},       
        complete: function (result) {                
            var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText); 
            if (response.error) {
            } 
            else { 
               bgDetails = response.d; 
                onSuccess(bgDetails.results);                 
            } 
        }         
 
    });       
}

function onSuccess(bgDetails) {
  
      $("#grid-data").bootgrid().bootgrid("append", bgDetails);  
      $("#grid-data").bootgrid("sort", { Column2 : "asc"}).bootgrid("search", $('.search-field').val());

      
      }
```

```css
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.2.0/jquery.bootgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.2.0/jquery.bootgrid.js"></script>
```

```html
<table id="grid-data" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" data-toggle="bootgrid" data-keep-selection="true">
<thead>
<tr>
<th data-column-id="Column1" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true" data-visible="false" >Employee ID</th>
<th data-column-id="Column2">Full Name</th>
<th data-column-id="Column5">Department</th>
<th data-column-id="Column7" >Work Phone</th>
<th data-column-id="Column9">Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of null

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in bootgrid when you work with `append` with a json containing `null` values for a searchable column.

You must make sure you don't have null values in any of your searchable column's rows. One way of doing this:

```
function onSuccess(bgDetails) {

    // iterate every row, and every property with null, and set an empty string...
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var row = array[i];
        for (var prop in row) {
            if (row.hasOwnProperty(prop) && row[prop] === null) {
                row[prop] = "";
            }
        }
    }

    $("#grid-data").bootgrid().bootgrid("append", bgDetails);  
    $("#grid-data").bootgrid("sort", { Column2 : "asc"}).bootgrid("search", $('.search-field').val());

  }
```

Another option would be to use their `ajax` instead of using `append` with something like this:

```
$("#grid-data").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    ajaxSettings: {        
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        headers: { 
            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(), 
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
        }
    },
    url: baseUrl
});


$("#grid-data").bootgrid("sort", { Column2 : "asc"})
               .bootgrid("search", $('.search-field').val());
```

...but you might need to change the server api response to fit the json they expect, which is something like this (see in [their examples](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples#data)):

```
{
  "current": 1,
  "rowCount": 10,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 19,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T20:15:00"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "total": 1123
}
```